# What's the difference between xp_fixeddrives and this query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

when i run xp_fixeddrives command to the drive that contains my tempdb, I obtain 10mb of free space, but the following query return other thing (45000 mb free).

other query :

```
USE tempdb;
GO
SELECT SUM(unallocated_extent_page_count) AS [free pages], 
(SUM(unallocated_extent_page_count)*1.0/128) AS [free space in MB]
FROM sys.dm_db_file_space_usage;
```

this drive only contain my tempdb db.

what is my error?

Comment: Why are you only counting unallocated pages? Are you trying to find free space in the tempdb data file(s), or free space on the drive itself? These are not the same thing.

Comment: Aaron, thanks.
I will find the free space on the drive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're querying two different things here.

`xp_fixeddrives` will show you the amount of free space on the disk.

Using `sys.dm` [views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174412.aspx) will tell you how much free space there is in the tempdb *data file*. If the data file is 50GB, then you're only using 5GB of it and the rest is empty. Even though it's empty, the file exists and is taking up 50GB of space on your drive.